How can I disable Chrome pop-ups like this while running automated Selenium tests in Python?
I am currently writing an automated testing suite for a large Django project for my corporation. Everything was going well until I updated Chrome (v.125.0.6422.142) and Chromedriver (v.125.0.6422.141). When I ran the tests, a Chrome Tip popped up from the vertical ellipsis that opens the Chrome menu:

I checked with a custom GPT (using GPT-4) to see if this was causing potential issues, and had it confirmed (for what it's worth) that this popup indeed would be causing interference in my tests. However, I am unsure of how to get rid of it.
I went through Stack OverFlow, GPT, and Github Copilot, and I implemented the following arguments to my setup:
def setUpClass(cls):
        super().setUpClass()

        if os.environ.get('ENVIRONMENT') == 'LOCAL':

            # Retrieve the path from an environment variable
            chromedriver_path = os.environ.get('CHROMEDRIVER_PATH')
            if not chromedriver_path:
                raise ValueError("The CHROMEDRIVER_PATH environment variable must be set.")
            chrome_service = Service(executable_path=chromedriver_path)
            
            # Option to run in headless mode
            if os.environ.get('HEADLESS') == 'True':    
                print("Running in headless mode.")
                chrome_options = Options()
                chrome_options.add_argument('--headless')
                chrome_options.add_argument('--enable-logging')
                cls.selenium = webdriver.Chrome(service=chrome_service, options=chrome_options)
            else:
                chrome_options = Options()
                chrome_options.add_argument('--disable-first-run-ui')
                chrome_options.add_argument('--no-first-run')
                chrome_options.add_argument('--disable-extensions')
                chrome_options.add_argument('--enable-logging')
                chrome_options.add_argument('--disable-popup-blocking')
                chrome_options.add_argument('--disable-notifications')
                chrome_options.add_argument('--disable-infobars')
                chrome_options.add_argument('--disable-blink-features=AutomationControlled')
                cls.selenium = webdriver.Chrome(service=chrome_service, options=chrome_options)
                cls.selenium.maximize_window()
                print("Running in headful mode")

The conditional statements are because of implementation logic for DevOps (we are junior devs in a startup), and I usually run the tests in 'Headful Mode'. No matter what I have implemented, the popup still shows and interferes with my tests. Even a simple button selection with an XPATH is not working and consistently times out or throws this vague error that I have been unable to find anything useful on other than a potential disconnect between Chromedriver and Chrome:

[13860:24408:0604/071320.491:ERROR:interface_endpoint_client.cc(722)]
Message 0 rejected by interface blink.mojom.WidgetHost

However given my ChromeDriver and Chrome versions, I strongly believe that this popup is the reason for my troubles. Any help is appreciated!

Are you sure that's the code you're running? super().setUpClass() looks wrong in this context

that prompt should not affect your tests.

One way of preventing that pop-up is by running with Incognito Mode:
chrome_options.add_argument("--incognito")

Also effective is Guest Mode:
chrome_options.add_argument("--guest")


Well, it got rid of that pop up, and I thank you very much for offering this solution! Sadly, that apparently wasn't my issue :(

But it does answer your original question: "How can I disable Chrome pop-ups like this while running automated Selenium tests in Python?"
